# SQL Native Client Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity, native-client

Application server for CRM has SQL native client 2008 version installed. I have installed SQL native client 2012 side by side as need to connect to an sql availability group listener. How do I get the application server to use the new client version? Oledb connection
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The OLE DB provider is usually specified via a connection string for database applications. Connection strings are usually stored in an external application configuration file so that the driver and other attributes (server, database, etc.) can be changed without code changes. Below is are SQL Server 2008 and 2012 Native Client examples, with SQLNCLI11 being the 2012 version:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Data Source=YourServer

Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Data Source=YourServer
```

Applications can also configure connection string properties programmatically or even have values hard-coded. Consult your CRM vendor documentation to determine specifics of configuration file locations or other configuration means, and importantly, verify the software supports SQL Server 2012 native client.

Comment: Many thanks Dan 

Comment: And note the current OleDB provider is MSOLEDBSQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15